# Mean and variance of a scaled Poisson random variable

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Suppose I have a variable, $Y$, that is a scaled Poisson random variable. That is:

$$ Y = kX $$

and

$$ X \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\mu) $$

This means that PMF of $Y$, $P(y)$, is given by:

$$ P(y) = e^{-\mu} \frac{\mu^{\frac{y}{k}}}{\left(\frac{y}{k}\right)!} $$

What would the mean and variance of $Y$ be in this situation? (Of course, the mean and variance of $X$ is just $\mu$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that PMF of $Y$, $P(y)$, is given by:

Close.   Always include the support in any pmf.$$\mathsf P(y) =  \dfrac{\mu^{\frac{y}{k}}e^{-\mu}}{\left(\tfrac{y}{k}\right)!}\mathbf 1_{y\in k\Bbb Z^+} $$

$k\Bbb Z^+=\{kx: x\in\Bbb Z. x\geq 0\}$

> What would the mean and variance of $Y$ be in this situation?

Scaled.

$\begin{split}\mathsf E(Y) &= \mathsf E(kX)\\[1ex] & =k\mu\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(Y)&=\mathsf{Var}(kX)\\[1ex]&=k^2\mu\end{split}$

Comment: Ah fantastic, thank you. My issue was that I have actual data that looks like $Y$, but I have no idea what $k$ is. So if I just take the ratio of the variance to the mean of my data I can estimate what the scaling is.

Comment: Sure, if it reasonable to suspect the distribution is a scaled Poisson, that will give a reasonable estimate.